# How to position an image in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I have a list of products, with a thumbnail and some information.

I make the cover image with css:

```
background-image: url("res://image"); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

but only this works if the image is stocked in the resources folder.

If I get the images from JSON file, all the background properties in the css not function.

[image]

I can make the image more large but the position not works.

I need to position an image to the center obtained from a URL (in JS)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use backgoundImage property of the layout and bind the image URL to it rather than giving it in the CSS.

```
<GridLayout [backgroundImage]="product.thumbnailImagSrc"></GridLayout>
```

Comment: Hi!!! Yes, you have the reason, with:                                                <GridLayout backgroundImage="{{ imgSrc }}"> </GridLayout>                       It works perfect, thanks